# PHP Pass Query statement as argument

Tags: php, pdo

guys im new to OOP and i have atleast 5 buttons with the same query for (Finished, Cancel, Add remarks etc....) the only difference is the Query statement. 
And im trying to put this in a Class and call the **SQL STATEMENT** as my argument. but it doesnt work. can you give me idea what is wrong or is there any workaround?. thanks!

```
      if(isset($_POST['cancel_job'])){
           $strcancel_remarks= trim($_POST['strcancel_remarks']);

           $sql =
                "UPDATE jrf_tbl SET 
                strremarks =  '$strcancel_remarks', //this is the only difference
                strstatus = 'Cancelled'     //this one also      
                WHERE ID =?";

           $set_id = 1;

           $obj = new myclass();
           $obj->updatequery($sql,$set_id)
          }

=====================
    class.php

        <?php

        include_once('dbc.php');

        class myclass{

        private $db;

        public function __construct(){

            $this->db = new Connection();
            $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
        }

        public function updatequery($sql, $set_id){
              $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindparam (1,$set_id);
                $stmt->execute();

                if($stmt->rowcount()==1){
                    echo "Updated Succesfully.";
                }else{
                    echo "There is an error";
                };
          }
        }
```

Comment: I've seen in a few questions that lettercase was the problem. I.e.: `bindparam` to `bindParam` and `rowcount` to `rowCount`. See if that makes it kick in.

Comment: It also looks like you're mixing mysqli syntax with PDO

Comment: @Machavity from what part? sorry im still new to PDO. but logically is it possible to pass the Whole SQL STATEMENT as an argument?

Comment: I don't use PDO myself. I'm more used to seeing params passed in an array to `execute()`. Still, PHP is Case Sensative and Fred is right that they need fixing. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Is $strcancel = trim($_POST['strcancel_remarks']); / SET strremarks =  '$strcancel_remarks' a copy/paste issue as $strcancel != $strcancel_remarks

Comment: @sean sorry typo error when i posted in here

Comment: @Fred-ii- i changes it to bindParam and rowCount but still not added to my database

Comment: UPDATED! it works now. i have no idea why. but maybe the lettercase issue solve the problem! thanks for your help guys!